# "is not" pattern and nullable types

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, nullable-reference-types

I have the following code:

```
#nullable enable
using System;
                    
public class X {
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var y = new object();
        if (y is not X notX){
            notX = null; // nullable warning generated here because notX is not nullable
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that although I can assign `null` to `notX` there is no way for me to declare it that way.

```
if (y is not X? notX)
```

yields me only compilation errors.

Is there a way of doing this?

Try it out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JoAeKL

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. `notX` should be unassigned anyway, or not?

Comment: Combining a declaration pattern with `not` is useless. In fact, Roslyn flags this as [IDE0059 - Remove unnecessary value assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0059).

Comment: Are you after `var notX = y as X`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Why is it useless? I thought it'd be useful but the compiler can't seem to handle it. The next snippet has an error. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/41WrZc

Comment: It is useless because it will _always_ be unassigned.

Comment: Why is it unassigned? I mean if it matched why doesn't it assign a value?

Comment: Because the matching is NOT X, while if you had if y is x, then it will assign y to x. It doesn't know what to assign to it

Comment: Because the assignment to `notX` only happens on the `true` case of the `is` and not on the `true` case of `is not`? So `is not` is not a pattern but only a shorthand for `!(y is X)`?

Comment: I guess this is way better than I said it @RedX

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `notX = null`. By definition it will only go into the if statement, if y is not of type X. Then the declaration pattern is always assigning null to notX.

`notX = null` creates a warning because you are assigning null to a non- nullable type.

The statement doesn't really make sense, because notX will always be null if the statement is executed. The only advantage would be that a variable notX with value "null" is created, but then it would also be cleaner to write following:

```
var y = new X();
if (y is not X)
{
    X? notX = null;
}
```

Comment: If you have a class hierarchy X might be a different class. So it's not always null.

Comment: @RedX What do you mean? If y is not X or a type that is derived from X notX would be null. If y is X or a type that is derived from X the if statement won't be executed

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the pattern matching with a nullable type without the variable:

```
if (y is not X?){
        
}
```

Then you'll see the exact error which forbids you from using a nullable type in this pattern, which is: `It is not legal to use nullable type X? in a pattern; use the underlying type 'X' instead.`

The same happens if you try to use any other nullable type.

This explains why you got compilation errors when you tried to use it, and why, on the other hand you get a `Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type` warning if you tried to assign null to `notX` in the first example. Simply because, when you use a declaration pattern here, a non nullable object is always expected.

If you really need a nullable object of type X, then one of the things to do would be:

```
X? notX; //or declare it locally inside the if block
if (y is not X)
{
    notX = null;
}
```

Comment: In a class hierarchy it might not be an instance of `X` but a different type.

Answer (score -1):

Why whats wrong with this?

```
if (y is not X)
{
    y = null;
}
```

Comment: That does something completely different to OP's code.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question.